# Google YouTube API Refresh Token not being sent

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to use the Google YouTube Data API with PHP based on Google's documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token. My problem comes in when authenticating with OAuth. I'm using the following authorization URL which is identical to the one the docs say to use except for my redirect uri and application key, obviously.

```
$this->authorizationUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
$this->authorizationUrl .= 'client_id=' . $this->applicationKey . '&';
$this->authorizationUrl .= 'redirect_uri=' . $this->redirect_uri . '/account.php?action=youtube_oauth&';
$this->authorizationUrl .= 'scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&';
$this->authorizationUrl .= 'response_type=code&';
$this->authorizationUrl .= 'access_type=offline';
```

Then, as the docs say to, I cURL the following:

```
$curl_options = Array(
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => Array(
                'code' => $code,
                'client_id' => $this->applicationKey,
                'client_secret' => $this->applicationSecret,
                'redirect_uri' => $this->redirect_uri . '/account.php?action=youtube_oauth',
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
            ),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
        );
```

However, my response never gives me a refresh_token like their documentation says it should. I just get the other three response items.

Some questions like this one: [Get refresh token google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api) have said to use approval_prompt=force, but that doesn't work either and entirely defeats the purpose of having access_type=offline.

Any ideas as to why I'd get a valid response with 3 of the 4 response items?

Answer (score 29):

From the [offline access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) portion of the OAuth2.0 docs:

> When your application receives a refresh token, it is
>   important to store that refresh token for future use. If your
>   application loses the refresh token, it will have to re-prompt the
>   user for consent before obtaining another refresh token. If you need
>   to re-prompt the user for consent, include the `approval_prompt`
>   parameter in the authorization code request, and set the value to
>   `force`.

So, when you have already granted access, subsequent requests for a `grant_type` of `authorization_code` will not return the `refresh_token`, even if `access_type` was set to `offline` in query string of the consent page.

As stated in the quote above, in order to obtain a **new** `refresh_token` after already receiving one, you will need to send your user back through the prompt, which you can do by setting `approval_prompt` to `force`.

Cheers,

PS This change was announced in a [blog post](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-oauth-20-endpoint.html) as well.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else suffering my own confusion, once you get a `refresh token` you don't need to _refresh_ it too as you can use the same one over and over again. The only time you should need a new one is if you lose it or the user revokes your access.

Answer (score 2):

You can try google oauth2 playground (https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) and see what the differences are between your params and there.