# Retrieving refresh token using oauth2 on Google Contacts API version 3.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I am using oauth2 (node.js and the [connect-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth) library) to connect to the [Google contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/).

Doing so, I get a response such as:

```
{ access_token : "...",
"token_typen": "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"id_token": "..." }
```

I am missing the refresh token used to get a new access token as soon as the latter is expired.

Options for OAuth2:

```
{ host: 'accounts.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/o/oauth2/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: 
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     Host: 'accounts.google.com',
     'Content-Length': 247 } }
```

post-body

```
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET&type=web_server&code=4%2F3gbiESZTEOjiyFPLUhKfE_a_jr8Q
```

NOTE: I tried to add `approval_prompt=force` from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api) to the request-post_body but this resulted in an Error

```
{ statusCode: 400, data: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_request"\n}' }
```

Answer (score 3):

> NOTE: I tried to add approval_prompt=force from a similar question to the request-post_body but this resulted in an Error

You don't need the `approval_prompt` param when you ask for a token. The *approval_prompt* param is for the authorization part.

---

> I am missing the refresh token...

The only way you DON'T get a *refresh_token* is when:

- use the [Client-side Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#clientside) flow;
- include the [access_type=online param](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl) in the authorization code request.

So, try adding: `access_type=offline`, to the authorization code request.

**Edit**:

i.e.:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=**your_client_id**&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&access_type=offline
```

If you're getting `400` is because you are adding an invalid parameter or missing one.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunantely that doesn't work either. I get an error: { statusCode: 400, data: '{ "error" : "invalid_request"}' }.

Answer (score 2):

One time I did this was testing - I had deleted the google authorisation token from the app - so it tried to get another one and it did but without a refresh token.

So check the app you are testing is not authorised for the account you are testing from (does that make sense?)

Comment: Google will only give you a refresh token once. After the initial auth, you will only get access tokens. You can get a new refresh token if you (or your users) remove access by visiting https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens and starting the auth sequence over from the beginning.

Comment: That is the answer that helped me. I was testing and trying to get refresh token from my own account (that I registered Google API on).