# YouTube api v3 debug oauth2 access token

Tags: oauth, google-api, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I get an oauth2 access token using the following scopes from the user.

```
scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"]
```

Then i proceed to use this token for calls to the youtube v3 api.  These calls work at first but then I start getting this response/error.

```
{ errors: [
  {
    domain: 'global',
    reason: 'authError',
    message: 'Invalid Credentials',
    locationType: 'header',
    location: 'Authorization'
  }],
  code: 401,
  message: 'Invalid Credentials'
}
```

Is anyone else experiencing this intermitten errors?  Is there a way to debug the oauth token like facebook [tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)?  Token seems to expire in 1 hour. [Get refresh token google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api)

example url

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels/?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics,topicDetails&mine=true&access_token={access_token}

Comment: Ok it appears that the token is expiring in a hour.  How can i get a longer token life?

Comment: tracked this url down.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}}

Comment: I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Token was expired. Had to use `approval_prompt=force,access_type=offline`. When requesting the `access_token`, this always gets a new refresh token. Then I used this refresh token to get a new token every time I needed to access the api on the user's behalf.

Useful tool for debugging google access token problems:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}