# Re get refresh token google api

Tags: google-api

i wrongly deleted Google refresh token for Google Drive API 
from Database.

i have only google token now

is there chance to get refresh token again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp), access tokens can be retrieved from refresh tokens, but not the other way round.

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api) further explains how to obtain refresh tokens. Once it is lost, you have to go through these steps again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually get a refresh token from the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).
If you are needing a refresh token for a Service Account as I was, make sure you

1. Click on the settings on the right.
2. Check *Use your own OAuth credentials*
3. Fill in your Client ID and Secret
4. Close the settings
5. Click the *Refresh* button on step 2
6. Then save the refresh token for use in your app