# Google Oauth not getting refresh token

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I am trying get refresh token. 
I read about it in google documents. 
Now, I am using accesstype offline and also approval_prompt: "force"
But I am not getting refresh token in response. 
I not getting what I am doing wrong.

I have following html code:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Google" onclick="authorizeWithGoogle()" />
```

Javascript code:

```
 var cid = 'XXXXX';
 var apik = 'XXXXX';
 var scopes = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';

 function authorizeWithGoogle() {
     gapi.client.setApiKey(apik); 
     gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: cid, scope: scopes,  accesstype: "offline"   ,approval_prompt: "force"}, handleAuthResult);
 }

 function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
     delete authResult['g-oauth-window'];
 if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(authResult));      
 }
}
```

Can you please help me.

Comment: Check this out, maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to be requesting refresh tokens as that negates the security of OAuth. Refresh tokens should only ever be requested/stored on a server. You might want to take a step back and review your understanding of OAuth before continuing. Trying to implement OAuth without understanding it is a pita.

For a browser client, you should simply keep calling gapi.auth.authorize whenever you need a new access token (eg. approx every hour). After the first call, you can set `immediate=true` which will suppress any UI.

Comment: thank you for reply. I read again and yes I have to get refresh token from server request. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

First, you made a typo, it's missing the underline: it's `access_type`, not `accesstype`.

Then, additionally to pass `access_type` and `approval_prompt`, you need to make sure your test user removed the grants for your app. Login in Google with your test account (not your app account) and go to [Account Permissions](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) and remove your app from the list.

Comment: if I change to access_type it is giving me error. access_type &#39;offline&#39; not allowed for response_type token

Comment: You need to pass `access_type` and `approval_prompt` at authorization code request, not during token request (i.e., when `response_type` is `code`).