# Trouble to keep gmail user logged in

Tags: reactjs, gmail-api

I am trying to build clone of gmail , and this is way i am doing login

```
 const login = useGoogleLogin({
    clientId:CLIENT_ID,
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      accessToken = response.access_token;
      console.log(response);
      
    },
    accessType:"offline",
    responseType:"code",
    prompt:"consent",
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
  });
```

the response that i recived contians access_token with expiry time ,

I want my user remain logged in so i wan't to refresh my access_token before it get expires but i am not getting any refresh_token in response

response :

```
access_tokenM: "ya29......."
authuser:  "0"
expires_in: 3599
prompt :  "consent"
scope: "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly 
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid                                                 
        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

can anyone help me to keep updating acces_Token before it get expires , thanks

Comment: You will only get a refresh token if you are using a server side programming language.   Due to security ramifications client side languages don't have refresh tokens

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thnks , I understood that from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858865/google-oauth-not-getting-refresh-token already but is there any way other than refresh token

Comment: Yes use a Server sided programming language