# How to get refresh token for Google Admin Directory API?

Tags: google-signin, google-authentication, google-admin-sdk, refresh-token

I'm using [Google Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/js) in my project.

I'm using Google sign first and then using access token to access this API, this access token expires after certain time. How I can get refresh token for long time so that I can access this API without having to re-signin?

***Edit***

first I'm doing google sign in following this npm package [google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) through this Im getting token to call users API
 by following method
here is my code to fetch google suite users

```
const a =localStorage.getItem('token')
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users? 
domain=${domain.url}&viewType=domain_public&key=${apiKey.key}`  
,{ headers: {
'authorization': 'Bearer '+a
 },})

   .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ users:data.users }));
```

Comment: Under what circumstances are you having to re-sign in? Please provide a sanitised copy of your code.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo have look now

Comment: [This is for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api) but the concept is the same, see if this helps you out at all