# Generate Refresh Token for a GCP OAuth 2.0 Client ID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I am trying to access to an API that uses OAuth2 authentication with the `Refresh Token` grant.

So, to request this API, I need a `Client Id`, a `Client Secret` and a `Refresh Token`.

Using https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials, I created a new `OAuth 2.0 Client ID`, which gives me a `Client Id` and a `Client Secret`.

But I struggle generating a Refresh Token.

By looking at [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/connecting-data-fusion-to-the-vision-api-via-oauth-restful-apis), it looks like I need to execute the following POST query :

`curl -X POST -d "code=[CODE]&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&grant_type=authorization_code" https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

To retrieve the `CODE` parameter, I need to do another call to this URL : `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=[SCOPE]&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]`

This call opens the Google login page.

[image]

However, I don't know how to log in with an `OAuth 2.0 Client ID`. I don't have an email linked to these credentials.

Am I following the correct steps to retrieve a `Refresh Token` in my use case, and if so, what am I missing here ?

Comment: After reading [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/connecting-data-fusion-to-the-vision-api-via-oauth-restful-apis#:~:text=NOTE%3A%20You%20may,a%20different%20org.) I assume that you should log in with your GCP user in order to get redirected to http://localhost:8080/....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get refresh token google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api)