# How to get refresh token from the 0auth2.0 in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, google-api

I want to get the refresh token from the google Api's but i don't know how i can get this Please anyone can tell me

Comment: Which api are you trying to access?

Comment: i want to get refresh token for the authorization in my nodejs app for email verification purpose. Because my old refresh token expires

Comment: So your trying to access the Gmail api?

Comment: Yes, please, you can guide me how to do that. Because when i register user then compiler give me GaxiosError: invalid grant due to expires refresh token

Comment: My apis is that when user register in my app an email sent to the user and then user verify the email with link that is provided in the email then user registered successfully and now user can login

Comment: If your refresh token has expired you need to request a new one. Run your app again and request consent of the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DalmTo but request not giving me refresh token

Comment: then please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer on getting [Google Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api) or check the official documentation on [Google Api](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens)

```
oauth2Client.on('tokens', (tokens) => {
  if (tokens.refresh_token) {
    // store the refresh_token in my database!
    console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
  }
  console.log(tokens.access_token);
});
```

To set the refresh_token at a later time, you can use the setCredentials method:

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: `STORED_REFRESH_TOKEN`
});
```

Once the client has a refresh token, access tokens will be acquired and refreshed automatically in the next call to the API.

**Note:** You should also know that The refresh_token is only returned on the first authorization.